# Suppose $X_1, \ldots, X_n\sim Pois(\lambda)$. Can an estimator $\hat{\lambda}$ of $\lambda$ contain $\lambda$ itself?

Tags: probability

Suppose $X_1, \ldots, X_n\sim Pois(\lambda)$. Suppose we define very naively an estimator of $\lambda$:

$$
\hat{\lambda} = \dfrac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}X_1
$$

Does this break any rules concerning whether an estimator can contain $\lambda$ itself?

Comment: The estimator can't contain $\lambda$ itself.

Comment: Thanks, is there an underlying theory why?

Comment: If your estimator is $\hat\lambda=f(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ and a particular observation is $X_1=x_1, \ldots, X_n=x_n$ then your estimate in that case $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is supposed to be a statistic of that observation rather than a function of $\lambda$.

Comment: The estimator is the function of random variables $X_1,\ldots, X_n$.So, if we given data $X_1=x_1,\ldots, X_n=x_n$, we can get the estimated value and it's not contain estimator.

Comment: Otherwise the best estimator would be simply $\hat\lambda=\lambda$, which would not help produce an estimate.